# Command button requires two clicks (sometimes)

Tags: button, click, command, icefaces

i am using icefaces 1.8.2. For some command buttons, sometimes i need to click the button twice. previously whole applivcation was working fine with single click. after upgrade to 1.8.2,i am  facing this problem......Any suggestion,what could be the reason???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some component loses the focus when you click the button. That could cause a partialSubmit and the server sends an update. This update replaces the part of your page containing the button.

But that a total wild guess into the blue.